# image swipe gesture in one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

okay I am learning more about swipe gesture, I have this signleviewactivity.java
its perfeclty displaying image , but how to make slide image without using fragments?
I read and I tested the [dev.android](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) but they are using fragments, **Can i work it without fragments?**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleview);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   //     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     //   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.funnyimage);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();


        ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("Person_List");

        if (personArrayList != null && !personArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Listitem person : personArrayList) {
                Picasso.
                        with(this).
                        load(person.url)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                        .fit()
                        .noFade()
                        .into(imageView);
                Log.i("PersonsActivity",String.valueOf(person.url));
            }
        }
       // GridViewAdaptersingle adapter = new GridViewAdaptersingle (getApplicationContext(), R.layout.singleviewadapter, personArrayList);

    }
```

Comment: without fragments? what do you mean? you have imageview and you want to swipe, but for what? I mean what action do you expect?

Comment: @piotrek1543 i am new to swipe gesture so as i understand i need to extend fragments .. then in my code i should a parent fragment that call singleview activity?

Comment: it depends what do you want to do it by swipe - in this concrete example yes you need